# Any cut function in numpy?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

```
y=np.array([0.4,0.5,0.6])
threshold=0.5

print(list(map(lambda x:1 if x>threshold else 0, y)))
[0, 0, 1]
```

Is there any function in numpy can do such job?

Comment: `(y > 0.5).astype(int)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [numpy.where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), along the following lines:

```
numpy.where(y>threshold, 1, 0)
```

which produces

```
array([0, 0, 1])
```

Comment: `np.where(x_bool, 1, 0)` is better spelt `x_bool.astype(np.int_)`, and much faster as `x_bool.view(np.int8)`